# How to find intermediate outputs of LSTM by running tf.nn.dynamic_rnn in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am new to tensorflow and have recently read about LSTM from various blogs like Understanding LSTM Networks, Colah, The Unreasonable Effectiveness of Recurrent Neural Networks, Karparthy etc.

I found this Code on the web:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def length(sequence):
    used = tf.sign(tf.reduce_max(tf.abs(sequence), reduction_indices=2))
    length = tf.reduce_sum(used, reduction_indices=1)
    length = tf.cast(length, tf.int32)
    return length

num_neurons = 10
num_layers = 3
max_length = 8
frame_size = 5

# dropout = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_neurons, state_is_tuple= True)
# cell = DropoutWrapper(cell, output_keep_prob=dropout)
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([cell] * num_layers)

sequence = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, max_length, frame_size])
output, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
    cell,
    sequence,
    dtype=tf.float32,
    sequence_length=length(sequence),
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        sample = np.random.random((8, max_length, frame_size)) + 0.1
        # sample[np.ix_([0,1],range(50,max_length))] = 0
        # drop = 0.2
        with tf.Session() as sess:
                init_op = init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
                sess.run(init_op)
                o, s  = sess.run([output, state], feed_dict={sequence: sample})
                # print "Output shape is ", o.shape()
                # print "state shape is ", s.shape()
                print "Output is ", o
                print "State is ", s
```

Pertaining to the above code with state_is_tuple= True, I have some doubts.

Q. What is the simple meaning of outputs and state which tf.nn.dynamic_rnn returns.

I read on the internet that output is the output of last layer at several time steps and
state is the final state.

My intermediate doubt is, what do we mean by "output of last layer at several time steps"

I looked into dynamic_rnn code as my main task is to find
(https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py)

Q. ***All the intermediate output of LSTM by calling dynamic_rnn in the same fashion as the above code. How can I do it.

I also read dynamic_rnn internally calls _dynamic_rnn. 
This _dynamic_rnn returns final_output and final_state. Apart from final_output. I want all the intermediate outputs.

My take is to write custom _dynamic_rnn as defined in 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py
Please help.

Comment: It would be very effective if someone can explain me via block diagram about the whole picture (layers in LSTM etc), which I have not understood.

Comment: For your first question regarding the returned values of tf.nn.dynamic_rnn, have a look at the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44162432/analysis-of-the-output-from-tf-nn-dynamic-rnn-tensorflow-function . Sorry but I don't know how to help with the rest.