# Analysis of the output from tf.nn.dynamic_rnn tensorflow function

Tags: tensorflow

I am not able to understand the output from `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` tensorflow function. The document just tells about the size of the output, but it doesn't tell what does each row/column means. From the documentation:

> **outputs**: The RNN output `Tensor`.
>
> If time_major == False (default), this will be a `Tensor` shaped:
>       `[batch_size, max_time, cell.output_size]`.
>
> If time_major == True, this will be a `Tensor` shaped:
>       `[max_time, batch_size, cell.output_size]`.
>
> Note, if `cell.output_size` is a (possibly nested) tuple of integers
>   or `TensorShape` objects, then `outputs` will be a tuple having the
>   same structure as `cell.output_size`, containing Tensors having shapes
>   corresponding to the shape data in `cell.output_size`.
>
> **state**: The final state.  If `cell.state_size` is an int, this   will
>   be shaped `[batch_size, cell.state_size]`.  If it is a
>   `TensorShape`, this will be shaped `[batch_size] + cell.state_size`.
>   If it is a (possibly nested) tuple of ints or `TensorShape`, this will
>   be a tuple having the corresponding shapes.

The `outputs` tensor is a 3-D matrix but what does each row/column represent?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[`tf.dynamic_rnn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn) provides two outputs, `outputs` and `state`.

- `outputs` contains the output of the RNN cell at every time instant. Assuming the default `time_major == False`, let's say you have an input composed of 10 examples with 7 time steps each and a feature vector of size 5 for every time step. Then your input would be 10x7x5 (`batch_size`x`max_time`x`features`). Now you give this as an input to a RNN cell with output size 15. Conceptually, each time step of each example is input to the RNN, and you would get a 15-long vector for each of those. So that is what `outputs` contains, a tensor in this case of size 10x7x15 (`batch_size`x`max_time`x`cell.output_size`) with the output of the RNN cell at each time step. If you are only interested in the last output of the cell, you can just slice the time dimension to pick just the last element (e.g. `outputs[:, -1, :]`).
- `state` contains the state of the RNN after processing all the inputs. Note that, unlike `outputs`, this doesn't contain information about every time step, but only about the last one (that is, the state *after* the last one). Depending on your case, the state may or may not be useful. For example, if you have very long sequences, you may not want/be able to processes them in a single batch, and you may need to split them into several subsequences. If you ignore the `state`, then whenever you give a new subsequence it will be as if you are beginning a new one; if you remember the state, however (e.g. outputting it or storing it in a variable), you can feed it back later (through the `initial_state` parameter of `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`) in order to correctly keep track of the state of the RNN, and only reset it to the initial state (generally all zeros) after you have completed the whole sequences. The shape of `state` can vary depending on the RNN cell that you are using, but, in general, you have some state for each of the examples (one or more tensors with size `batch_size`x`state_size`, where `state_size` depends on the cell type and size).

Comment: This, but I believe `state` additionally holds the state at every layer of your network. So if you are using a GRU, you would have a state for the output of your candidate and gate layers, and if your GRU was the cell for a multi-layer RNN, you would have these states for every layer in your network.

Comment: @Engineero Yes, that's right, thanks. I didn't give much detail, but state for multi-layer RNN cells would be a list of states of each individual cell, for LSTM cells would be a pair of tensors and so on.

Comment: @jdehesa - Could you please take a look at this another question that I raised? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44116689/siamese-model-with-lstm-network-fails-to-train-using-tensorflow

Comment: @jdehesa is "15" the number of hidden units in your hidden layer in the discussion of "outputs"?

Comment: @StatsSorceress Well, you could say that. Strictly speaking, that would only be the case for plain recurrent layers, since advanced structures like LSTM or GRU are more complicated and therefore have more actual "units". But, conceptually speaking, if we are only talking about the number of outputs of the layer, then yes.