# Conceptual understanding of tf.nn.dynamic_rnn() "outputs" vs. "state"

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

### Context

I'm reading through part II of [Hands on ML](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491962291) and am looking for some clarity on when to use "outputs" and when to use "state" in the loss calculation for a RNN.

In the book (p.396 for those that have the book), the author says, "Note that the fully connected layer is connected to the `states` tensor, which contains only the final states of the RNN," referring to a sequence classifier that is unrolled over 28 steps. Since the `states` variable will have `len(states) == <number_of_hidden_layers>`, when building a deep RNN I have been using states[-1] to only connect to the final state of the final layer. For example:

```py
# hidden_layer_architecture = list of ints defining n_neurons in each layer
# example: hidden_layer_architecture = [100 for _ in range(5)]
layers = []
for layer_id, n_neurons in enumerate(hidden_layer_architecture):

    hidden_layer = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(n_neurons, 
                                               activation=tf.nn.tanh,                                                                                                                                                                     
                                               name=f'hidden_layer_{layer_id}')

    layers.append(hidden_layer)

recurrent_hidden_layers = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(layers)
outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(recurrent_hidden_layers,
                                    X_, dtype=tf.float32)

logits = tf.layers.dense(states[-1], n_outputs, name='outputs')
```

This works as expected given the author's previous statement. However, I don't understand when one would use the `outputs` variable (first output of `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn()`)

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44162432/analysis-of-the-output-from-tf-nn-dynamic-rnn-tensorflow-function), which does a pretty good job of answering the minutia, and mentioned that, "If you are only interested in the last output of the cell, you can just slice the time dimension to pick just the last element (e.g. `outputs[:, -1, :]`)." I inferred this to mean something along the lines of `states[-1] == outputs[:, -1, :]`, which when tested was false. Why would this not be the case? If the outputs are the outputs of the cell at each time step, why wouldn't this be the case? In general...

### Question

When does one use the `outputs` variable from `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn()` in the loss function and when would one use the `states` variable? How does this change the abstracted architecture of the network?

Any clarity would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: FYI: "Tagging" somebody in the comments does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This basically breaks it down:

`outputs`: Full sequence of outputs of the top-level of the RNN. This means that, should you be using `MultiRNNCell`, this will only be the *top* cell; nothing from the lower cells is in here.
In general, with custom `RNNCell` implementations, this could be pretty much anything, however pretty much all the standard cells with return the sequence of *states* here, however you could also write a custom cell yourself that does something to the state sequence (e.g. a linear transformation) before returning it as *outputs*.

`state` (note that this is what the docs call it, *not* `states`) is the full state of the *last* time step. One important difference is that, in the case of `MultiRNNCell`, this will contain the final states of *all* cells in the sequence, not just the top one! Also, the precise format/type of this output varies heavily depending on the `RNNCell` used (e.g. it could be a tensor, or a tuple of tensors...).

As such, if all you care about is the top-most state of the last time step in a `MultiRNNCell`, you really have two options that should be identical, coming down to personal preference/"clarity":

- `outputs[:, -1, :]` (assuming batch-major format) extracts only the last time-step from the sequence of top-level states.
- `state[-1]` extracts only the top-level state from the tuple of final states for all layers.

There are other scenarios where you might not have this choice:

- If you actually need the full sequence output, you need to use `outputs`.
- If you need the final states from lower layers in a `MultiRNNCell`, you need to use `state`.

As for why the equality check fails: If you actually used `==`, I believe this checks for equality of the tensor *objects* which are obviously different. You could instead try to inspect the *values* of the two objects for some simple toy scenario (tiny state size/sequence length) -- they should be the same.

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you. The equality (`==`) test was testing the equality of the objects and upon further inspection the values within the Tensor were the same. Substituting `output[:, -1, :]` into the loss function instead of `state[-1]` yields similar results.